# Xamarin and System.Data.SqlClient: example use cases

Tags: xamarin

What purpose would the `System.Data.SqlClient` library serve in a mobile app? What are some example use cases where an app would need that library to communicate  with SQL Server directly, i.e. not via a web-service running on a remote website?

Answer (score 0):

On Android you could talk to a SQL server instance that is provided by an installed service or other App.

Or if for some reason you do not want to use the native SQLite capabilities and your App starts a SQL server instance on App launch.

Answer (score 0):

It's not unusual, if not best practice, to have an SQL server open to the public, other security mechanisms may exist.  More likely for internal use only enterprise apps that are in a controlled network, eg wifi, there are advantages in talking direct to he database, saves the overhead and code maintenance of a web api in the middle.